# Mysql: using max(date) to grab just the most up to date rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, mytableA and mytableB.

MytableA looks like this

```
ColumnA|Columnb
Apple|fruitstand
Pear|fruitstand
```

mytableB looks like this:

```
ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC
Apple|2|4/1/2012
Apple|3|4/3/2012
Apple|23|12/1/2011
Pear|1|12/22/2011
Pear|0|4/22/2012
```

the query I have is this

```
select * 
from 
  mytableB 
  join mytableB on mytableA.ColumnA = mytableB.ColumA
     and mytableB.Columnc = (select max(Columnc) from mytableB b where b.ColumnA = mytableB.columnA)
```

The result i'm looking for is

```
 Apple|3|4/3/2012
Pear|0|4/22/2012
```

I know this works in SQL but does mysql have a similar way?

Comment: Did you make a typo in your query when you renamed some of the tables/columns? It doesn't look like `myTableB.ColumnB` has any relationship with `myTableA.ColumnA` (from your join)

Comment: Mike, I think your query is still not edited correctly. You are currently joining `myTableB` with `myTableB`.  I assume you mean to join `myTableA` with `myTableB` on `columnA`. I just tried my interpretation of your query, and it's returning the two rows, each having the MAX date for each fruit.  What result are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried it out. it works (excluding tons of typos) on mysql but the result does not make any sense to me.

```
ColumnA | ColumnB       | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC
Apple     fruitstand      Pear      0         4/22/2012
Pear      fruitstand      Pear      0         4/22/2012
```

EDIT: you sould use some kind of index to identify the entries.

like
mytablea

```
ID | name | type
```

mytableb

```
ID | fruitID | stock | date
```

then

```
SELECT mytablea.name, mytableb.stock, mytableb.date FROM mytablea, mytableb, 
       (SELECT MAX(mytableb.date) as maxDate FROM mytableb, mytablea 
       WHERE mytableb.fruitID = mytablea.ID GROUP BY mytablea.ID) AS maxTB 
       WHERE mytableb.date = maxTB.maxDate AND mytablea.ID = mytableb.fruitID
```

should do the trick ... it's some lame large subquery :-!

result:

```
name | stock | date
Apple  4       4/3/2012
Pear   0       4/22/2012
```

Comment: i want to select the data from mytableB where there is a 1 to 1 relationship between mytablea and mytableB where the data in mytableB where only be there the date is max

Comment: the problem i'm getting is it only selects rows where columnc is max, so meaning even though there is 2 rows in mytableA (apple,pear) it returns only pear because pear has a greater date

Comment: i've done some large update ;) sry that i didn't get it the first time ;)

Comment: that's strange, i always worked with mysql so it's a pain i'm used ;) but i donno if there is a shorter solution ... EDIT: sry got a typo in my result. it should be stock 3